# SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect. when trying to connect to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

Its says in my package manager console that the connection was successfully established with the server, but an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) I am trying to initialize and seed a database through my C# application and this was after I tried to Update-Database.

I have pretty much tried every solution I found online. This is how my connection string looks like right now.

> "DefaultConnectionStrings": "Data Source=(LocalServer);Initial Catalog=(DatabaseIamtryingtoaccess);Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;User Instance=False"

I have swapped out the certificates and used no certificate either and the issue doesnt seem to be going away.

Comment: that comes because you set TrustServerCertificate=True; see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trustservercertificate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0  see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3299/how-to-configure-ssl-encryption-in-sql-server/ if you really want a ssl connction

Comment: `Data Source=(LocalServer)` is not a syntax I'm familiar with. For the local machine, either use `Data Source=.` or `Data Source=(local)`. And obviously if you are using an encrypted connection you need a certificate that matches the name of the machine and is issued by a CA that your machine trusts (rather than a self-signed certificate)

Comment: So which driver are you actually using to connect? With `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` version 5 and later, for example, the `Encrypt` property isn't `True` or `False`, it's `Optional`, `Mandatory` or `Strict`. Additionally, unless you're using the `HostNameInCertificate` property on newer drivers to override it, then the name or IP address you use in the `Server` property should be mentioned in the instance's certificate's CN or one of its SubjectAltName properties.

Comment: @nbk I am a little confused. Prior to this I had used encrypt = false and excluded the trust server certificate = true but the result was still the same. From what I have gathered online, I believe that it should help to bypass the certificate chain completely and since I am using a self signed certificate, would it not help me to sick the certificate validation and just allow me to connect straight away.

Comment: by default, sql browser(service) is deactivated) if you installed a fresh server you should read one or more tutorials how it must be configured, without configuration nothing will go

Comment: @nbk sure I will try installing a fresh server and configuring it properly